# SQL update - leaving out MIN amount of records, based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, window-functions

I have a "News" table, which has one-to-Many with "NewsState" table. Need to make an update on  NewsState field called "expired" (to set to true), depending on the value of  "date" field in "News" table, on these conditions

- if date is older than 24 hours, it's related NewsStates should be expired.
- if there is less than 50 "News" in last 24 hours ( lets say there was 10 News) then 40 latest News which are older than 24 hours should also not be expired, so that always MIN 50 is unexpired.
- If there was more than 50 News in last 24 hours, their NewsStates should also not be expired.

I have no solution coming to my mind which does not include some heavy sub-selects and IN clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is can be done with [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html), f.ex.:
(I assume you have a single `news_id` as primary key in `News` table -- also that's the foreign key in `NewsState`--, if that's not the case, you can use the `ROW()` constructor to compare multiple columns within the `IN` expression. I also assume `expired` is of the `boolean`.)

```
update NewsState set expired = news_id in (
  select news_id
  from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by date desc)
    from News
  ) n
  where  date > (now() - interval '24 hour')
     or  row_number <= 50
);
```

[Some SQLFiddle samples](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ffd9a/15) (with different rule numbers for simplicity).